# AngularJS + Socket.io: Socket events triggering modal—inside a directive or controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I'm using socket.io to send an event to an Angular controller, which sets the text content for a modal template.

If I also want to call a `modal()` method when that event is fired, should I do this inside the controller, or should I do it inside a directive?

If it's the latter, should I listen for the socket.io event directly inside the directive, or should I broadcast a separate event from the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with the latter using a combination of including socket.io via dependency injection (as referenced in rgaskill's answer, and then reacting to the socket event itself in the directive, like so:

```
angular.module('MyApp.directives', [])
  .directive('modal', function(socket) {

    return function($scope, element, attrs) {
      socket.on('showInfo', function(event, msg){
        element.modal('show');
      });

    };
  });
```

**EDIT**

A quick update here:  For longer-term organization's sake, I ended up putting all of my `socket` listeners inside my controllers instead of sprinkling them throughout both the controllers and directives.  When I needed to listen for events in the directives, I used angular's `$scope.$broadcast('eventName')` inside the controller's socket listener to broadcast the events to the directive, which then caught them with `$scope.$on('eventName')`.   Some redundancy there, but it helped enforce a level of consistency that wasn't present before.

If anyone has input into the relative effectiveness or ineffectiveness of this technique, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

I have typically taken the approach described by Brian Ford [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/).

Comment: I didn't see any DOM actions triggered via sockets in his example, so I wasn't sure how to proceed.  Upvote, as I did leverage the dependency injection in his example and ultimately figured it out on my own.